# Roblox Studio output error [Argument 1 missing or nil]

Tags: roblox

I want to make a sinking ship game in roblox. I got an error "Argument 1 missing or nil" 
I want to make the ship rotate, but there is a problem in output.
Heres script:

```
wait(10)

X=script.Parent

for i= 8, 100 do

X:TranslateBy(script.Parent:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(script.Parent:GetPrimaryPartCFrame()*CFrame.Angles(-0.2, 0, 0.1)))
    wait(5)
    end
```

How can I rotate my ship?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to remove the `X:TranslateBy()` as translateby won't rotate your ship. (It takes in a vector)

As for the error, SetPrimaryPartCFrame does not return anything, which is why you are getting an error for TranslateBy